# Disable resizing snap view in Windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, css, windows, winjs

I'm working with a Windows 8 app using **Java Script.**

In windows 8 there is only one snap view and that is fixed one. But when we come to the windows 8.1 we can resize the snap view. I want to do is keep that fixed size snap view in windows 8.1 also. That means, I want to stop resizing snap view when my windows 8 app running on windows 8.1..

Is there any way for it...?

Looking for example or any guide... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dougajmcdonald is correct. The user is in control and will be able to resize any app to most any size, so your app will need to account for it. You can change the minimum size of your app which gives Windows a hint about where to give the user a snap point. For instance, if you say your app's minimum size is 500px then when the user is dragging the separator, it will snap to 500 pixels, but it will still allow them to resize to say 587 pixels.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness. Actually how I set snap points using JS..? Can you show me a sample. I think that will really help for me...

Comment: You set it in the tooling, and not in the language. If you double click on the package.appxmanifest, it will open a UI and one of the fields is "Minimum Width". That will determine where the primary snap point is. Windows will give another snap point at 50%.

Comment: Is that feature in VS2013..?  Actually I can't find it in VS2012

Comment: Right, it's in VS2013. You need VS2013 to make Windows 8.1 apps, so that's what I assumed you were using. If you are working on a Windows 8 app (using VS2012) you still won't have any control over what happens with the resizing of your app for users on Windows 8.1. If you have a snapped view and an 8.1 user stretches your app larger than snapped (>320 pixels), it will render vertical black space on each side of your app and your app will remain 320 pixels wide.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much **Jeremy Foster**. You gave me lot of support here. Thanks. I followed some courses in MVA few weeks ago..You really did well there.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can stop it, as it's a part of the OS and apps are supposed to adhere to it.

You can control your app via media queries in the CSS to fix size to particular values when the app width is at certain values.

Or you can detect the application state and look for 'snapped' and set sizes in the JS code perhaps.

EDIT:

In order to use CSS which applies to the application in snapped mode you can find good examples in the MS Template applications, taken from their CSS you can use:

```
@media screen and (-ms-view-state: snapped) { // my styles }
```

Which will allow you to apply specific styles in the snapped state.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind support. can you share some sample JS code for that..?